# Hide and Show table column and display all column together

Tags: jquery

I have created hide/show table column by checkbox it's working good now after clicking checked checkbox table column being hidden but I'm facing problem to make table display all column together in one table. Here is my code:

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      let column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
      $(column).toggle();
  });

  $("#display-all").click(function(){
      let column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
      $(column).show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="display-all" type="button">Display all</button>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="id" checked>ID</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="catalogue" checked>Catalogue Name</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="id">ID</th>
        <th class="catalogue">Catalogue Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">56797</td>
        <td class="catalogue">DIESEL S NENTISH W EU-39</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you have name attribute on checkbox but not on the button
And you want to show ALL `th` and `td` inside `table tr` on button click

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      let column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
      $(column).toggle();
  });

  $("#display-all").click(function(){
      $("table tr th, table tr td").show();
      $("input").prop("checked", true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="display-all" type="button">Display all</button>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="id" checked>ID</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="catalogue" checked>Catalogue Name</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="id">ID</th>
        <th class="catalogue">Catalogue Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">56797</td>
        <td class="catalogue">DIESEL S NENTISH W EU-39</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```